# Is it possible to hide a specific FlyoutItem when using Xamarin Forms Shell?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am using Xamarin Forms Shell and I want to be able to hide some items of my Flyout depending on some parameters (the current page for instance) but I can't find any method or property to change the visibility of a FlyoutItem.

Is it possible to programmaticaly hide some FlyoutItem (not the complete Flyout just some items) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible with Xamarin.Forms 4.8 version.
you can use Isvisible attribute to show/hide any flyout item.
Please refer below link for more details :

[Xamarin.Forms v4.8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/release-notes/4.8/4.8.0)

[GitHub Issue Resolved](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/5232)

Answer (score 4):

As of this moment it is not possible, there is a [current Issue regarding this.](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/5232)

However, I managed to find another thread, where there might be a solution with dynamic creating flyout items. You can check it [here.](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/5428)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, here is my solution.
I created a style, and set that to hidden.
Then I update my MenuItem in the backend, depending what is needed.

Style

```
<Style
            ApplyToDerivedTypes="True"
            Class="MenuItemLayoutStyleHidden"
            TargetType="Layout">
            <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="False" />
        </Style>
```

Menu Item

```
<MenuItem
    x:Name="btnLogout"
    Clicked="btnLogoutClick"
    IconImageSource="icon_about.png"
    StyleClass="MenuItemLayoutStyle"
    Text="Logout" />
```

Backend Code

```
if (user.isLoggedIn)
        {
            btnLogout.@class.Clear();
            btnLogout.@class.Add("MenuItemLayoutStyle");
        }
        else
        {
            btnLogout.@class.Clear();
            btnLogout.@class.Add("MenuItemLayoutStyleHidden");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

this works for me
flyoutxname.FlyoutItemIsVisible = false;

where flyoutxname is the x:Name property for the flyoutitem.

```
<FlyoutItem Title="item title" x:Name="flyoutxname" Icon="byebye.jpg">
```

source
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/flyout

Comment: Hey, it looks like the second line got cut off? I think you meant "where flyoutxname is the name of your flyout"?

Comment: yesss sprry. the flyoutxname is the x:Name property for the flyoutitem

Answer (score 0):

I was searching how i can hide a **MenuItem** in Shell Flyout because i didn't want to use **FlyoutItem**. I needed the Clicked event. I managed to hide a **MenuItem** with:

```
<MenuItem Text="Arrivals" x:Name="Arrivals" Clicked="MenuItem_Clicked" Shell.FlyoutItemIsVisible="False"/>
```